# Using Win2D, how to crop an image to a circle

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

It seems like this should be simple enough, but I'm really struggling with finding any documentation on how I can do this.  I'm simply looking to crop an image to turn a square into a circle.

There is a lot of discussion about it, but I can't seem to find a good example of how to do this using UWP/Win2D.

Here is a bit of code to illustrate the issue I was trying to describe in my comments:

```
// draw a 10x10 grid of circles
var bitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "Assets/ice.png"); // hex-shaped image is 250x220 pixels 
var brush = new CanvasImageBrush(sender, bitmap);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        //_drawingSession.FillCircle(new Vector2(i * 50, j * 50), (float)(25), Colors.Blue);
        _drawingSession.FillCircle(new Vector2(i * 50, j * 50), (float)(25), brush);
    }
}
```

The image below shows how the brush is being cut from the same x/y coordinates based on the vector where the target circle is to be drawn.

Note: the same effect occurs with FillEllipse().

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after chatting with one of the fellows on the GitHub Win2D project, I finally have a clear answer on how this works - and it works nothing like I would have expected it to work.

First, the bitmap brush image is by default being positioned at 0,0 on the canvas.

In my case, I wanted to cut a circle from the image and draw it someplace else on the canvas.  This requires 2 separate bits of math.

First, you need to position the bitmap's top-left-corner (TLC) to where you want the circle to be drawn.  This is done by setting the brush's Transform property.  In my example, I'm setting the image TLC to 300/300;

```
// create the brush
var brush = new CanvasImageBrush(sender, _tiles[1]);
brush.Transform = Matrix3x2.CreateTranslation(300, 300);
```

Now, to cut/draw the circle using the brush image, I have to describe where the center of the image is to be on the canvas.  My image is 250x220.

```
// 300+250/2, 300+220/2 = 425, 410
_args.DrawingSession.FillCircle(new Vector2(425, 410), (float)(110), brush);
```

This gives the effect of cutting a circle out of my original bitmap and drawing it on the canvas at the desired location.

Hopefully this is clear enough.  I know I certainly struggled to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [CanvasImageBrush](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Brushes_CanvasImageBrush.htm) and [CanvasDrawingSession.FillEllipse Method](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession_FillEllipse.htm) achieve it.

```
private async void canvas_Draw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasControl sender, 
    Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
    using (CanvasBitmap bitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "Assets/image.jpg"))
    {
        CanvasImageBrush canvasImageBrush = new CanvasImageBrush(sender, bitmap);
        args.DrawingSession.FillEllipse(new System.Numerics.Vector2(100f), 100, 100, canvasImageBrush);
    }
}
```

**------------ Update -------------**

If you want to cut a circle out of the image source, you can configure the `CanvasImageBrush.Transform` property to scale the image, then cut the circle and display it on the canvas.

```
private async void canvas_Draw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasControl sender, 
    Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
    using (CanvasBitmap bitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "Assets/image.jpg"))
    {
        CanvasImageBrush canvasImageBrush = new CanvasImageBrush(sender, bitmap);
        System.Numerics.Vector2 center = new System.Numerics.Vector2((float)(bitmap.Size.Width / 2),
            (float)(bitmap.Size.Height / 2));
        canvasImageBrush.Transform = System.Numerics.Matrix3x2.CreateScale(0.5F, center);
        args.DrawingSession.FillEllipse(center, 160, 160, canvasImageBrush);
    }
}
```

You should change some parameters in my above code to satisfy your requirement, such as the scale in the `Matrix3x2.CreateScale` method.

Comment: This seems to somewhat work, but it looks as though the center point (and possibly the radius values) are being used as offsets within the image used for the brush as well.

Comment: When I switch out the brush for a solid color, I successfully draw a grid of circles.  However, when the brush is being used, only one of the circles is correctly drawn.  The rest either come out looking like smears, or there is no image at all being drawn.

Comment: After further investigation, it looks to me like the first parameter in the list is being used as both the target coordinates of where the Ellipse is being drawn, as well as the offset from the bitmap being used as the brush.  This seems to be why everything outside of bounds 220x250 (which is the size of my bitmap) is being drawn as blurred streaks.  I'm not sure if this is a bug in Win2D or if this is an intended "feature".

Comment: So could you provide more code to make me see your issue and the detailed effect you want?

Comment: I've updated the original post to show the problem I was describing above.  In my case, I'm not looking to make a grid of circles, but I need to use an image as a source, cut a circle out of it, and then redraw that circle on the canvas.  The 10x10 grid shows that I can't do what I want to do using FillCircle and a bitmap brush.

Comment: It looks like I'm not the first person to report this issue.  However, I'm still stuck then with how to cut a circle out of a source image and draw the circle to the canvas.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730646/win2d-library-canvasimagebrush-paints-using-the-canvas-coordinates

Comment: You mean to cut a circle image which is part of a source image then draw the circle image on the canvas? If so, I think you can change the Vector2(center) and the radius to cut the image circle on the canvas.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  I have a square image.  I want to cut a circle out of the square image and then draw that circle image onto the canvas.  The way it is, I cannot use the canvas brush because if I set the target coordinates on the canvas to some point that is larger than the brush image, it fails.

Comment: @PaulMouchet I have updated my answer, you can check it and use a transform to scale the image to cut it as your want.

Comment: Liu - the suggestion does not improve the situation.  The problem with the CanvasImageBrush is that the coordinates that are supplied to the FillCircle/FillEllipse are being used for both the offset into the brush image and the canvas.  This surely has to be a bug with how those methods work. My bitmap image I'm using is 250x220.  It I try to use the bitmap brush at any canvas coordinates larger than 250x220 the operation fails.  It doesn't crash, but it will not successfully draw the circle.  I tried to show this in my code and illustration above.  The brush transform does not help.